# Showing undifine variable inside of foreach loop in php using laravel filepond

Tags: php, laravel-blade, filepond

my $gallery showing undefile in laravel blade, but i am getting data on $images. i am using laravel with filepond

```
            <?php if(count($images)): ?>
            pond.setOptions({
                files: [
                    <?php foreach($images as $gallery): ?> {
                        source: "{{ asset('storage/' . $gallery->image) }}",
                        options: {
                            id: "{{ $gallery->id }}",
                            type: 'local'
                        },
                    },
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                ]
            })

            <?php endif;?>
```

[the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDGZg.png)

trying to get value from $images as $gallery in for each but it showing undefine, as $images getting value as expected but not getthing value as $gallery in  foreach($images as $gallery).

Comment: Due to the mix of native PHP syntax, and blade templating syntax, I suppose? Your `<?php foreach($images as $gallery): ?>` is "classic" PHP, but `source: "{{ asset('storage/' . $gallery->image) }}",` is outside of the PHP block. So to me it looks like the template parser now expects a variable, that was never defined on the template "level". Why is this not using `@foreach` syntax?

Comment: well, if i use @foreach then Filepond's script not worked properly...

Comment: Well then you probably used it incorrectly, resp. did not make it produce the exact output required. Btw., "assembling" this in the template, is really rather ugly to begin with. You should rather populate the corresponding data structure in your controller, and then just output the whole thing in one go, using `json_encode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it appears that I'm trying to embed PHP code within a JavaScript block, utilizing Blade templating syntax in the context of Laravel. The challenge here is the potential conflict between Blade's `@foreach` and JavaScript's curly braces.

To address this issue, I've opted to use the `@json` directive. This directive is handy as it converts the PHP array into a JSON string, making it safe to include within the JavaScript code. Here's the updated version of the code I came up with: `

```php
<?php if (count($images)): ?>
    pond.setOptions({
        files: {!! json_encode($images->map(function ($gallery) {
            return [
                'source' => asset("storage/{$gallery->image}"),
                'options' => [
                    'id' => $gallery->id,
                    'type' => 'local',
                ],
            ];
        })) !!}
    });
<?php endif; ?>
```